# Exchange Server 2003 - Set Full Mailbox Access permission for every new user

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

We have an Exchange Server running, we're trying to connect with it from an application in another server. Thing is, we have to set some permissions for it to work (we want to access any mailbox with an Administrator mailbox, but we have to set it Full Mailbox Access first). We somehow need to set this for every new user at the moment it's created. Could you tell us how do we do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821897

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is , type following command in the Exchange Management Shell

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "" -User "" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All

Using Exchange Management Shell commands, you can do many useful things easily.